# Realm Section Dates from db?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, realm

I' m doing simple task app where when you adding a new task you must fill Name, and date on which will task start.

I want to order my tasks by date in sections like this.

[image]

```
class Task: Object {

    dynamic var name = ""                       //  názov úlohy
    dynamic var notes = ""                       //  poznámky úlohy
    dynamic var created_at = NSDate()    //   dátum vytvorenia úlohy
    dynamic var planned_at = ""              //   dátum vykonania úlohy
    dynamic var isCompleted = false        //    status úlohy
}
```

This is my model for saving data

From Browser

[image]

How its possible to do it? I've been finding some questions here but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

If the number of rows is a little or fixed, an easy way is creating section management object(e.g. Dictionary ``) and fill value yourself.

Please see the Realm's GroupedTableView Example https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/GroupedTableView

**2.**

If there are large numbers of rows or variable rows, the most efficient way is define section object and link with `Task` object. The following like:

```
class DueDate: Object {
    dynamic var date: String = "" // DD MM, YYYY
    dynamic var task: Task?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "date"
    }
}
```

Then you append a `Task` object to the `DueDate` every creating the `Task` object.

```
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(task.created_at)
var dueDate = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(DueDate.self, key: dateString)
if dueDate == nil {
    dueDate = DueDate()
    dueDate.date = dateString
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(dueDate, update: true)
    }
}
dueDate.tasks.append(task)
```

Now, you can get sections like the following:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let sections = realm.objects(DueDate)
    return sections.count
}
```

Realm's relationships are represented as a native link. So a cost of relationships is really cheap. Is this answer your question?

Comment: From what did you get tasks? in dueDate.tasks.append(task)

Comment: and how i'll get title for section my dates from planned_at?

Comment: The `task` is what you created or user selected, I mean. A user can push "+" button, or select a task, right? The former case, you may create new task object. The latter case you get task object from selected row, I think. At that time, you can connect `DueDate` and `Task`.

Comment: If the section title is `planned_at`, `DueDate.date` should be `planned_at`. I thought the title is `created_at`, sorry.

Comment: tried it also tried customize it but only with empty title section and 2 sections where i have same tasks in 2 sections. I've invited you to chat if you have time i want to ask about it.

Comment: @patrikbelis Yes, I can.

Comment: @patrikbelis Sorry, I've just entered the chat.